# get an error "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" on iterate over product(row[1])

Tags: python-3.x

I tried the below code but after 200 product iteration it stops and gives error("ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"). please help me to handle this (in terminal it gives error on iterating)

```
for row in dataset.iter_rows():
    
    try:
        response = requests.get("http://109.205.152.56/urls/?country=in&query="+row[1])
        data = response.json()
    

        parsed_data = {
                "price":[i["price"] for i in data["known"]],
                "url":[i["url"] for i in data["known"]] }

        data_as_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed_data,orient="columns")
       
        data_as_df.to_csv('/Amazon_prod.csv',mode = 'a', header=None)    

    except:
        continue
```

Comment: try adding a sleep function at the end of try block. ```time.sleep(1)``` or something like that. The server might have closed your request because you are frequently requesting resources from the server.

Comment: still gets same error after 200 iterations it gives("ConnectionResetError", During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred that is "raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)"